# scaled y ticks=false don´t work together with loglogaxis?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I´ll like to remove the multiplier on the y axis. My wish is to get somethings like,
0.001, not 1.10^-3. Can somebody help me please

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Die Präambel
%
\documentclass[ english,                                %   Verwendete Sprachen, englische Rechtschreibung, Daten, etc.
                ngerman,                                %   Verwendete Sprachen, neue deutsche Rechtschreibung, Daten, etc.
                11pt,                                   %   Standardschriftgröße des Dokumentes
                twoside=false,                          %   twoside false = einseitiger Druck; true = zweiseitiger Druck 
                open=any,                           %   Gibt an auf welcher Seite das nächste Kapitel beginnen soll. Möglichkeiten sind: any, left, right
                DIV=14,                             %   DIV=calc
                BCOR=12mm,                          %   Bindekorrektur in mm
                toc=listof,                             %   Nimmt das Abbildungs- sowie Tabellenverzeichnis in das Inhaltsverzeichnis auf
                toc=index,                              %   Nimmt den Index in das Inhaltsverzeichnis auf
                bibliography=totoc,
                headsepline,                            %   Linie unter Kopfzeile
                plainheadsepline                        %   Linie unter Kopfzeile
                ]
                {scrartcl}                              %   KOMA-Script Klasse Report
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.3}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
%---------------neue package-------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
log ticks with fixed point,
grid=both,
xlabel=Cost,ylabel=Error,
scale ticks above=2,    
]
\addplot coordinates {
(5, 8.31160034e-02)
(17, 2.54685628e-02)
(49, 7.40715288e-03)
(129, 2.10192154e-03)
(321, 5.87352989e-04)
(769, 1.62269942e-04)
(1793, 4.44248889e-05)
(4097, 1.20714122e-05)
(9217, 3.26101452e-06)
};
\addplot coordinates {
(7, 8.47178381e-02)
(31, 3.04409349e-02)
(111, 1.02214539e-02)
(351, 3.30346265e-03)
(1023, 1.03886535e-03)
(2815, 3.19646457e-04)
(7423, 9.65789766e-05)
(18943, 2.87339125e-05)
(47103, 8.43749881e-06)
};
\legend{Case 1,Case 2}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for me if I remove the `scale ticks above=2` option. What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: I have removed this option, but nothing new happened. I really don´t know exactly...May be the 1.3. How can I get it faster?

Comment: Could you check your `.log` file for a line starting with `Package: pgfplots`? It should tell you the version number there. Also, which distribution (TeXLive? MikTeX?) and operating system are you using?

Comment: Thanks! I get the follow information by giving "Package: pgfplots" as search words : Package: pgfplots 2011/07/29 v1.5 (git show 1.5-1-gcc2f2d2 ). What I have to know the version of PGFplots? I use MikTeX and Texnic center...

Comment: Okay. You might want to try updating to the current version, which is 1.7.